# Контроллер "избранное"

Tags: ios, xcode, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

У каждого нижнего ViewController в NavigationBar добавлена кнопка:

```
// Добавляем иконку "Избранное" в NavigationBar
UIBarButtonItem *favoritesItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(favButtonPressed)];
NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[favoritesItem];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;

// Нажата кнопка "избранное"
-(void)favButtonPressed
{
   // Видимо тут и надо описать переход
}
```

Каким образом я могу перейти в верхний ViewController, чтобы у того так же был NavigationBar, кнопка "назад" и возможность вернуться в контроллер, из которого и был осуществлен переход?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для начала Вам необходимо добавить на контроллер Storyboard ID, на который Вы хотите перейти. Например, "view".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь есть два способа перейти.

**1.Начнем с PresentViewController**

```
ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

В ViewController, на который мы перешли, должны добавить кнопку назад

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Назад" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(dismissView)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
}

-(void)dismissView
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**2.Есть так же и второй способ - PushViewController**

```
ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Кнопка не видна, но нажать её можно